# python - scipy.integrate.odeint returning wrong results

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I was trying to integrate a square wave using python 3.5 and the `scipy.integrate.odeint` function but the results don't make any sense and vary wildly with the array of time points selected.

The square wave has a period of 10sec and the simulation runs for 100sec. Since the array of time points has size 500, there will be 50 time points on each period of the square wave, but that doesn't seem to be happening.
Using the optional parameter `hmax=0.02` fixes it, but shouldn't it be inferred automatically?

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate

# dx/dt = f(t),  where f(t) is a square wave
def f(x, t):
    return float(t % 10.0 < 5.0) * 0.3

T = 100
tt = np.linspace(0, T, 500)
xx = integrate.odeint(f, 0, tt, hmax=0.2)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(tt, xx)
plt.axis([0,T,0,16])

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(tt, [f(None,t) for t in tt])
plt.axis([0, T, 0, 1])
plt.show()
```

I'm hoping someone can put some light into what is happening here.
Try changing `T` between 80 and 100 (simulation time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the odeint function takes continuous Ordinary Differential Equations which a square wave is not.

i'd start by redefining your square-wave function to:

```
def g(t):
    return float(t % 10.0 < 5.0) * 0.3
```

then define a function to calculate the integral step-by-step:

```
def get_integral(tt):
    intarray = np.zeros_like(tt)
    step_size = tt[1] -tt[0]
    for i,t in enumerate(tt):
        intarray[i] = intarray[i-1] + g(t)*step_size
    return intarray
```

Then:

```
xx = get_integral(tt)
```

should give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that odeint only deals with continuous functions. Do you know if there are there other integrators available that can integrate discontinuous functions? The Euler method that you proposed works in this case but is a poor solution in general.

Comment: I don't think there is a more general method @Miguel. I fear your question is more of a mathematical one rather than a programming one.  The get_integral method above could be modified to the Trapezium Rule which in many cases would yield better results, but in the instance of the square-wave would create errors.  I certainly don't know of any 'general' method either mathematical or computational.